# Recurring subscription payments service

Tags: paypal

I hope somebody can point me in the right direction. I'm a newcomer to web design and I've just had a client ask could I set up a subscription service on his website. I thought this would be fairly straighforward but lo and behold I cannot find a service that provides what my client needs.

Basically, he does newspaper deliver in our local area. What he needs is for customers to go to his website, enter their address and contact info. The next step is they are able to choose which newspaper and on which day they receive it. Finally a custom subscription is set up for each user according to their choices. I cant seem to find a subscription service which offers such parameters - I've checked places like Recurly, Chargebee, Paypal etc. but no luck. Could someone please offer any advice or at least point me in the right direction? Would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're going to need to setup the form to gather the user data on your end and then just pass everything into a subscription request to PayPal using either Payments Standard upload command method or Express Checkout Recurring Payments.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew, although that sounds like a large amount of manual work! The client is looking for a setup pretty much the exact same as whats on this website - www.reachhomedelivery.ie - amazingly I can't find anything similar to this (other than the actual company who provide this software of course). Manually adding this information would almost defeat the purpose. Would something like Zapier be beneficial in taking out the manual labour? Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

[Recurly](http://www.recurly.com) would be able to handle this (full disclosure, I work for Recurly!). Essentially it's a two step process - first, you collect their name and address information and pass that into an [account create call](https://dev.recurly.com/docs/create-an-account). The second step would be choosing their subscription plan, and passing the starts_at parameter to Recurly in the [subscription create call](https://dev.recurly.com/docs/create-subscription) to start their subscription on the day they choose.

Recurly's ability to pass custom pricing, include add-ons in the subscription pricing, and even setup fees would support most any type of purchase choices a customer is making.